# Use jquery to find the cell of a table without text inside

Tags: jquery

I getting some issue with jquery and selectors.

I have some HTML tables on my page with this structure

```
<table class="table-array-radio">
  <colgroup class="col-responses">
    <col class="col-answers" style="width: 33%;">
    <col class="ls-col-odd" style="width: 6.1%">
    <col class="ls-col-even" style="width: 6.1%">
    <col class="ls-col-odd" style="width: 6.1%">
    <col class="ls-col-even" style="width: 6.1%">
  </colgroup>
  <thead">
    <tr>
      <td class=""></td>
      <th class="answer-text">0</th>
      <th class="answer-text">1</th>
      <th class="answer-text">2</th>
      <th class="answer-text">3</th>
      <th class="answer-text">4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="answers-list">
        <th class="answertext control-label">sotto-domanda 1</th>
        <td class="answer_cell_1 answer-item radio-item"></td>
        <td class="answer_cell_2 answer-item radio-item"></td>
        <td class="answer_cell_3 answer-item radio-item"></td>
        <td class="answer_cell_4 answer-item radio-item"></td>
        <td class="answer_cell_11 answer-item radio-item"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I simplify the table, but the structure is this.
I have to check with JQuery if in my body I have a cell with class ".answertext" that contain any text, and if the cell is empty I have to set the width of the ".col-answers" class to '0'.

I'm using this

```
$('.table-array-radio').each(function(obj,i) {
    var check = $(obj).find('.answertext').text();
    console.log(check); 
});
```

But check is always empty. I have three table on my page, one with some text in the cell and the other two without any text. But my console is always ""

Why?

Comment: first look `(obj,i)` should be `(i ,obj)`

Comment: Hi, is it the empty string, or it may have some whitespaces? You might want to use  `.text().trim()`, or use the `:empty` selector: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-empty-pseudo *“The `:empty` pseudo-class represents an element that has no children except, optionally, document white space characters.”*

Comment: nagyon kell kakilnom, most mit csináljak?

Comment: always debug.... `console.log('obj:', obj);console.log('i:', i);console.log('elem:', $(obj).find('.answertext'));`

Answer (score 0):

So first of all here in your html you have error, you need to remove this symbol "

```
</colgroup>
  <thead">
```

after that you need to fix little thing here, you need to swap obj, i

```
$('.table-array-radio').each(function(i, obj) {
    var check = $(obj).find('.answertext').text();
    console.log(check); 
});
```